# ListBox SelectedItems Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind Listbox selectedItems to array. But .NET throws exception at runtime.

```
d.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemsProperty, new Binding { Source = SomeArray });
```

Where `d` is some ListBox from XAML.

Exception:

> Selected Item cannot be bound.

Why?

Answer (score 9):

You can subscribe to the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox, and in the handler sync a collection of selected items.

In this example the Windows DataContext was set to itself (this) in its constructor.  You could also easily call into a logic layer (ViewModel if you're using MVVM) from the event handler.

In Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>

    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
    </ListBox>

    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}">
    </ItemsControl>

</StackPanel>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        SelectedItems.Remove(item);
    }

    foreach (string item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        SelectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work as OneWayToSource binding. If I change the SelectedItems collection, then the changes are not reflected in the listbox.

Comment: @BogdanVerbenets Maybe setting Mode to TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged will do the trick?  By the way, we have the same first name! :D

Comment: Downvoted because suggesting the use of an event handler in code-behind to call into a view model doesn't follow the MVVM pattern.

If you don't mind code-behind (and I do mind it, but whatever), then use this. But please, don't pollute view models by calling into them from code-behind.

Answer (score 5):

This is the working solution, however when selection changes SelectedItemsProperty does not refresh bindings...

you can create a custom control as follow

```
public class MyListBox: ListBox{

    public MyListBox()
    { 
         this.SelectionChanged += (s,e)=>{ RefreshBindings(); };
    }

    private void RefreshBindings()
    {
         BindingExpression be = 
             (BindingExpression) GetBindingExpression(
                                      SelectedItemsProperty);
         if(be!=null){
               bd.UpdateTarget();
         }
    }

}
```

or in your app you can define event in every listbox as shown below ..

```
myListBox.SelectionChanged += (s,e) => {
    BindingExpression be = 
         (BindingExpression) myListBox.GetBindingExpression(
                                      ListBox.SelectedItemsProperty);
    if(be!=null){
        bd.UpdateTarget();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a working solution, you could easily adapt to your needs:

In `xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxSelectedItems.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ProductListSource, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        SelectionMode="Multiple" >

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListBox>
    <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListBoxSelectedItems
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : MyNotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ProductListSource.Add(new Product() { Item = "Item_1", IsSelected = false });
        ProductListSource.Add(new Product() { Item = "Item_2", IsSelected = false });
        ProductListSource.Add(new Product() { Item = "Item_3", IsSelected = false });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductListSource
    {
        get => _productList;
        set
        {
            _productList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ProductListSource));
        }
    }

    private readonly Product _selectedProduct;

    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get => _selectedProduct;
        set
        {
            var selectedItems = ProductListSource.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedProduct));

            string s = "{";
            int n = selectedItems.Count;
            for (int i=0; i< n; i++)
            {
                s += selectedItems[i].ToString();
                if (i < n - 1) s += ", ";
            }
            s += "}";
            Debug.WriteLine(s + ".Count= " + n);

        }
    }
}

public class Product : MyNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _item;

    public string Item
    {
        get => _item;
        set
        {
            _item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Item));
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
    }

    public new string ToString() => _item;

}

public class MyNotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly or the exact scenario - but assuming you wanted to have one listbox "d" show the items that were selected in another listbox "MyOtherListbox" then you just need to set the binding mode to 'one way' else it will bring up an error.

You could do something like

```
d.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = MyOtherListbox.SelectedItems, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay});
```

Comment: I must use something Like this:

d.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemsProperty, new Binding { Source = SomeArray, Mode=OneWay });
But it raise the same exception.

Comment: No, you cannot bind to the SelectedItemsProperty since it only has a get accessor.

I think the closest you will get to this is if you read the following thread...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f0183ef3-ee0e-4de9-86c7-73d2072baba7

Comment: This will not refresh if selected items are changed, because SelectedItems is List and not an observable collection or binding list.

Comment: Thanks Polaris - does that mean the thread answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox.SelectedItems` is read-only. Did you mean to bind to `ListBox.SelectedItem` instead?

Comment: No I have several selected items and I want to show them in ListBox in selected state

Comment: Since that property is read-only, you can't use it for what you want. The only thing I can think of is to set individual `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` properties. If you insist on binding, the easiest path would be for you to create e.g. an attached SelectedItems `DependencyProperty` with custom logic in property changed event handler.

Answer (score 1):

my trick: in xaml, use `MultiBinding`, force execute converter in `Count` property change (it work!).

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedRowsTotal }">
    <Binding Path="SelectedItems"  ElementName="listBox1" />
    <Binding Path="SelectedItems.Count"  ElementName="listBox1" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Converter:

```
public class SelectedRowsTotal : IMultiValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        var selecteds = values as IEnumerable;

        if (selected == null) 
            return null;

        return selecteds.Cast<SomeType>().Sum(x=> x.SomeProperty) = total;
    }

    object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MVVM is the bees knees now a days, using behaviours is really the simplest way out I could find, when respecting viewModel principles.

First catch the event and send it to an iCommand in the viewModel

Xaml:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectorFiles}" x:Name="Box">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=Box}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:
Grab it, pack it, cast it and do your happy dance.

```
public class XXXViewModel()
{
  public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> SelectorFiles { get; set; } = new();
  public List<FileInfo> SelectedFiles { get; set; } = new();

  public ICommand OnSelectionChanged { get; set; }

  ctor()
  {
    OnSelectionChanged = new DelegateCommand<object>(Format());
  }

  private Action<object> Format()
  {
    return items =>
    {
    SelectedFiles = (items as ObservableCollection<object>).Cast<FileInfo>().ToList();
    // or do stuff :)
    };
  }

}
```